# Is it possible to use template haskell to get the name of the current file?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

The closest I can see is using [`reifyModule`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:reifyModule) and [`thisModule`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:thisModule), but that doesn't work.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

main = putStrLn $(LitE . StringL . show <$> thisModule)
```

(unsurprisingly) gives back `Module (PkgName "main") (ModName "Main")` regardless of the file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it using [`location`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:location%60).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

main = putStrLn $(LitE . StringL . loc_filename <$> location)
```